# How to export a multidimensional array in which each element is also an array?

Tags: matrix, export, import

I have a {15,5,2} dimensional array and each element is itself a {14,16} dimensional array. When I export/import my file as an excel file I get a {15,,5,2} dimensional array but with {} dimension for each element. Somehow it doesn't recognize each element as a matrix. Does anybody know how I can solve this problem?

Thank you.

I noticed I cannot use excel for higher dimensions, but using HDF5, I still get error.

Comment: What Mathematica version ?

Comment: 11.2 but it was my bad using Excel format I guess. Do you know any other formats work properly? I examined .dat also, but changes the dimensionality

Comment: Do you need to open these files in any program other than Mathematica? If you don't, then I often use ".mat" files. They import and export really quickly and are good at keeping arrays the same. The one caveat is that when you import a matrix, you have to go `matrix[[1]]` (or whatever your matrix name is) as the ".mat" format adds an extra `{}` around the overall array but doesn't mess with the components.

Comment: IMHO, `hdf5` is the way to go. Much more efficient than `.mat` because it supports higher multidimensional tensors natively.

Comment: Thank you so much, I keep getting this error: Export::errelem: The Export element Datasets contains a malformed data structure and could not be exported to HDF5 format.

Comment: and also: Export::type: {<<1>>} cannot be exported to the MAT format. but when I use .dat the dimension changes to {15, 1825}